# onPageFinished/onPageStarted in WebViewClient is never called

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I am writing a little web application for Android and I need to get some JS variables from HTML page, but code in setParam(final String str) is never called.

Also, code in onPageStarted(...) and onPageFinished(...) is never called too, and I can't suppose why.

```
void startPageParse()
{
    WebView web = new WebView(context);

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(){
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void setParam(final String str)
        {
            setParamFromJS(str);
        }
    }, "JSInterface");

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap fav)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, fav);

            Log.v("WebCLI", "Started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.loadUrl("javascript:JSInterface.setParam(flashvars['pl'])");

            Log.v("WebCLI", "JSCalled");
        }
    });

    web.loadUrl(SeasonURL);
    Log.v("WebCLI", "Load called");
}
```

If I set breakpoint at "web.loadUrl(SeasonURL)" it works(!) and those lines will be in logcat:

```
08-28 13:22:12.766    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
08-28 13:22:12.875    4294-4356/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
08-28 13:22:15.290    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp V/WebCLI﹕ Load called
08-28 13:22:15.610    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@425157a8 time:786230
08-28 13:22:15.625    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp V/WebCLI﹕ Started
08-28 13:22:20.586    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp V/WebCLI﹕ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
08-28 13:22:20.586    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source: %SOMEURL% (1)
08-28 13:22:24.469    4294-4294/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSApp V/WebCLI﹕ JSCalled
```

This also work if this activity as main.

Comment: First question: `INTERNET` permission granted in the manifest?

Comment: yes, INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE are granted in manifest

Comment: When are you calling `startPageParse`?

Comment: In the constructor method

Comment: I guess I'll need to see some logs then or something... If you're calling this method in `onCreate`, `context` is, indeed, the Activity, you have the appropriate permissions, and `SeasonURL` resolves with a 200 status, then the only flaw I see is the javascript call, but that can be solved after you're able to load the page.

Comment: I've added some logs to post

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with your JS call in those logs. Be sure to add the `;` at the end of the JS line. I've also posted a method I implement within custom webviews for handling JS code. Also, `loadUrl` is done asynchronously (so is `evaluateJavascript`), which might explain why adding break points allows your code to recover.

Answer (score 0):

For the JavaScript calls, you'll want to use a different method for KitKat and beyond. Specifically `evaluateJavaScript()`. Normally I would `extend WebView` and implement this method within the WebView, but this modified method should work if you run it on the right thread. Below is a method that you can call that accommodates the new and old javascript calls:

```
public void injectJavaScript(WebView view, final String javascript) {

    if (javascript == null || javascript.isEmpty() || !this.isPageFinished) {
        return;
    }

    // As of KitKat, evaluateJavascript(String javascript) should be used over loadAd("javascript:(javaScriptMethod())")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        String js = "javascript:" + javascript;
        view.loadUrl(js);
    } else {
        // Returns the value of the executed JavaScript as a JSON string.
        view.evaluateJavascript(javascript, new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String stringCallback) {
                //If you'd like any response from the JS to confirm the execution
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, where you are calling the JS in your `onPageFinished()` it will look something like:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    String jsString = "JSInterface.setParam(flashvars['pl']);";
    injectJavaScript(view, jsString);

    Log.v("WebCLI", "JSCalled");
}
```